# What's wrong with my solution of indefinite integration of a piecewise function?

Tags: calculus

The question asks for the current across an inductor of L = 0.2H given a voltage: $-4t + 2$ from $0.25s <= t <= 0.5s$. The formula is $V = L*di/dt$

The initial condition is 0.625 Amps.

I get: $$\frac{1}{0.2} \int -4t + 2 dt = 5*(-2t^2 + 2t + c)$$

Because of the initial condition, the constant is 0.625 A. However, the current time $t_{new} = t_{old} - 0.25s$

So plugging in,

$$5(-2(t-0.25)^2 + 2(t-0.25)+0.625) = -10t^2 + 15t$$

Which is wrong. Why?

Comment: All I can say that $5(-2(t-0.25)^2 + 2(t-0.25)+0.625) = -10t^2 + 15\color{red}t$

Comment: yes sorry that's what i meant.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly the input data, you can put
$$
I(t) = \frac{1}
{L}\int {Vdt}  = 5\left( { - 2t^{\,2}  + 2t + c} \right)
$$
but then to calculate the constant you shall put
$$
I(0.25) = 0.625 = 5\left( { - \frac{1}
{8} + \frac{1}
{2} + c} \right)\quad  \Rightarrow \quad c =  - 0.25
$$
which gives
$$
I(t) = 5\left( { - 2t^{\,2}  + 2t - 0.25} \right)\quad \left| {\;0.25 \leqslant t \leqslant 0.5} \right.
$$
Otherwise you shall put
$$
t = \tau  + 0.25\quad V(\tau ) =  - 4\tau  + 1
$$
and get
$$
\begin{gathered}
  I(\tau ) = \frac{1}
{L}\int {Vd\tau }  = 5\left( { - 2\tau ^{\,2}  + \tau  + c} \right) \hfill \\
  I(0) = 0.625 = 5\,c\quad  \Rightarrow \quad c = 0.125 \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
In conclusion
$$
\begin{gathered}
  I = 5\left( { - 2\tau ^{\,2}  + \tau  + 0.125} \right)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \tau  \leqslant 0.25} \right. \hfill \\
   = 5\left( { - 2\left( {t - 0.25} \right)^{\,2}  + \left( {t - 0.25} \right) + 0.125} \right) \hfill \\
   = 5\left( { - 2t^{\,2}  + 2t - 0.25} \right)\quad \left| {\;0.25 \leqslant t \leqslant 0.5} \right. \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$

Comment: So what's wrong with my method?

Comment: @Goldname: the value assigned to $c$ + the way of replacing  $t_{old}$ with $t_{new}$

Answer (score 0):

we have

$$\frac{di}{dt}=5(-4t+2)$$

$\implies$

$$i=\int_{0.25}^{0.5} 5(-4t+2)dt$$

$$=-10(0.25-0.0625)+10(0.5-0.25)$$

$$=0.625 A.$$